# Load a component as child component in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am using angular 6 and trying to import a component as child component.

I have a component which can be accessed by routing to `'/register'` which loads `signUpComponent` and and I have other component which loads `ServicesComponent` using `'/services'` and also I am using both the routes in multiple components.

Now my problem is that I want to load `ServicesComponent` as child component of `SigUpComponent` i.e. something like this `'/register/services'` (kind of nested routing) with condition that my both routes are defined separately. Is there any way to do it, instead of redefining a third route as `'/register/services'` with `ServicesComponent` defined as child component of `SigUpComponent`

Comment: I do not know what exactly you are looking for but have you tried this? https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component

Comment: Did you check on angular website? Its there

Answer (score 2):

You can use children routing like this ::

```
const parentModuleRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parent-component',            //<---- parent component declared here
        component: PetParentComponent,
        children: [                          //<---- child components declared here
            {
                path:'child-one',
                component: ChildOneComponent
            },
            {
                path:'child-two',
                component: ChildTwoComponent
            },
            {
                path:'child-three',
                component: ChildThreeComponent
            },
            {
                path:'child-four',
                component: ChildFourComponent
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

You can use this links for more informations ::

https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component(As per @wannadream says)

https://itnext.io/child-routes-with-respective-components-in-angular-4-36f1be42278e